# Difference between try block placement in java

Tags: java

I'm curious as to what difference will it make if I placed the try block outside of a for loop versus inside of the for loop? As in if I were to write it like this:

```
try{
     for(int a : array){
          //some code here
     }
}catch(Exception e){}
```

Versus something like

```
for(int a : array){
     try{
          //some code here
     } catch(Exception e){}
}
```

Will there be a difference in how the exception is processed? 
I understand that by putting the try inside the forloop, the try statement will execute and test the code each time the for loop loops. But what about when putting the for inside the try statement?

I hope what I wrote makes sense

Comment: The difference is whether the loop will continue after an exception is caught.

Comment: In the first case if there is an exception, then flow will exit the `for` loop

Comment: @ScaryWombat so does that mean if there's an error detected in, say the first iteration of the for loop, the entire for loop stops, goes to try to find a matching catch block, then to the first statment after the try statement? It will never go back to re-loop anymore?

btw thanks both of you for helping

Comment: In the first case if there is an exception thrown from processing the nth element, then the loop will proceed no further

Comment: i see, thank you for replying

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes**. Wrapping the loop around the try block, means the loop will continue in the face of the exception; trying the next iteration. With the try block around the loop any exception will terminate the loop. In either case (in real code), you should not silently swallow exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean by silently swallow exceptions?

Comment: @Schnitzel it means that you should do something about the exception. At least print the stacktrace to know where the exception raised for further review later.

Comment: @Schnitzel `catch(Exception e){}` You didn't do anything with the Exception; handle it (at least log it). Otherwise, you should *probably* allow it to propagate; else you know not what occurred.